# Spring bean overwrite for SoapMessageDispatcher

Tags: spring-boot, spring-ws

in Spring-WS there's a `SoapMessageDispatcher extends MessageDispatcher`,
I need to rewrite the receive function so I can do my customised logging inside it.
So I have like `MyDispatcher extends SoapMessageDispatcher`. But the thing is,
the parent class `MessageDispatcher` expects the existence of MyDispatcher.properties in resource path
but our project can't have this file in resource folder. the only permitted is the application.properties
for the Springboot Application.

Their could be multiple solotuion, I can write my own `MessageDispatcher` and have a different constructor
doesn't need a property file for example. But I was just wondering if there's any easier way.

Is it possible that, I create a package `org.springframework.ws.soap.server` and name my class `SoapMessageDispatcher`,
same as that class in Spring-WS. So that when my application starts, my version of `SoapMessageDispatcher` is used to
create the bean, but the `SoapMessageDispatcher.properties` inside the Spring-WS.jar is used.

So that's your own class + properties files in Spring-WS.jar, it's like the Spring-WS version of `SoapMessageDispatcher`
is overwritten. I tried it on my machine, seems always the Spring-WS version class being used to create the bean. Does anyone
know if there's way to make this solution work?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need to extend that class to do logging? What is so special that you need to extend that class?

Comment: I need to control the types of Soap mesage to be logged. Some messages could have large payload.